# How to show searchboxes in footer using YII 2.0 grid

Tags: gridview, yii2

How can we show search boxes in footer using yii2 grid. I have tried but it is showing extra tr due to **'showFooter' => true,** property. My code looks like this.

```
 <?=
        GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'filterModel' => $searchModel,
            'filterPosition' => 'footer',
            'showFooter' => true,
            ],
            'columns' => [
                ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn',
                    'header' => 'S.No.'
                ],
                --columns--
               ],

                ?>
```

as you can see extra tr showing before searchboxes. I want to remove this tr in every case (searching, sorting).

What should I need to do find my solution, please help.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use filterPosition whit proper constant value

```
GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'filterPosition' => GridView::FILTER_POS_FOOTER,
        'showFooter' => true,
        ],
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn',
                'header' => 'S.No.'
            ],
            --columns--
           ],

            ?>
```

see this for more http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-gridview.html#$filterPosition-detail

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-gridview.html#FILTER_POS_FOOTER-detail

Comment: it is throwing error ->  Use of undefined constant FILTER_POS_FOOTER - assumed 'FILTER_POS_FOOTER'

Comment: Yiu are using  yii\grid\GridView or a  gridview from an extension (eg:kartk gridview)  ?

Comment: I think value of FILTER_POS_FOOTER is footer defined in gridview class

Comment: If I use     'filterPosition' => 'footer',
                'showFooter' => true, then footer is shoing right but that extra tr is hsowing before filter

Comment: You should use GridView::FILTER_POS_FOOTER and showFooter = true.. answer  updated

Comment: But that extra tr is still showing before search boxes as you can see in attached screenshot

Comment: seems that adding showFooter = true show the empty row but  without the showFooter value  the filter on FOOTER is not showed .. could be this is the Yii2 gridview behavior  ..

Comment: yes you right @scaisEdge. it is yii2 gridview behaviour

Comment: there may be any solution

Comment: I already tried jquery but it removes tr but I am using pjax on this page that due to this tr apears again

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution just add property

**'footerRowOptions'=>['style'=>'display: none;'],**

on gridview widget. This will not display that extra tr before searchboxes in footer. Hope it will help someone.